# Radon transform range theorem and radial functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms, inverse-problems, integral-geometry

(**UPDATED** for rapid decay considerations + new question)

In dimension 2, the Radon transform range theorem states that a *rapidly decaying* (Schwartz) function $g(t,\theta)$ can be represented as a Radon transform of some function $f(x,y)$ (i.e. $g=R[f]$) if and only if, for all integers $n\geq0$
$$P_n(\theta) := \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} t^n g(t,\theta) dt$$ is a homogeneous polynomial *of degree* $n$ in $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$.  This is often referred to as the *moment* or *Cavalieri conditions*.  See e.g. Helgason's book p.5, Lemma 2.2 (2011 ed.) for the property that $P_n$ must be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$.

**Question 1**: If $f$ is a radial function then its Radon transform $g=R[f]$ is known to be independent from $\theta$.  Therefore all moments $P_n(\theta)$ are also independent from $\theta$, in apparent violation of the property that $P_n$ is a homogeneous polynomial in $\cos\theta, \sin\theta$ of degree $n$ when $n\geq1$.  What am I missing?

For example, consider $f(x,y) = e^{-x^2-y^2} / \sqrt\pi$.  Then $g(t,\theta) = e^{-t^2}$ which is independent from $\theta$ as expected of radial functions.  The first moment is 0 which is NOT a homogeneous polynomial of degree 1, the second moment is $\sqrt\pi/2$ which is NOT a homogeneous polynomial of degree 2, and so forth.

**Question 2:** What happens when the above integral does not converge?  Usually this happens when there is no solution to the Radon transform inverse problem, but consider $g(t,\theta) = (1-e^{-1/t^2})/|t|$ which is independent from $\theta$.  After calculations, the inversion formula for radial function gives $$f(x,y) = f_0\!\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right), \qquad f_0(r) = \frac2{\pi r^3}\mathfrak D\!\left(\frac 1r\right)$$ where $\mathfrak D(x) := e^{-x^2}\int_0^x e^{t^2} dt$ is Dawson's function.  So there exists $f$ such that $g=R[f]$, and yet 
$$
P_n(\theta) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} t^n \frac{1-e^{-1/t^2}}{|t|} dt
$$
does not converge for $n\geq 2$.

**My partial answer to Q2**: This specific example is not a Schwartz function.  Any references to range theorems for non-Schwartz functions appreciated.  I found "A Range Theorem for the Radon Transform" (Madych and Solmon, 1988), other suggestions very appreciated.

Thanks!
p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer Q1: There are trig identities at play. First, 0 is usually accepted under the definition of "homogeneous polynomial" (i.e., it's a polynomial whose coefficients are all zero) so there is no contradiction there. But for the case of the second moment being constant, we have the identity $\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1$, so actually a constant is representable by a homogeneous trig polynomial of degree 2 polynomial, so again, no contradiction.

**Edit:** for Q2, The moment conditions can indeed be violated when the function is not Schwartz. A good reference for this is the paper:

Solmon, D. C. (1987). *Asymptotic formulas for the dual Radon transform and applications*. Mathematische Zeitschrift, 195(3), 321-343.

The main theorem of this paper shows that the inverse Radon transform maps any even Schwartz function $\phi$ over $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}\times \mathbb{R}$ to a $C^\infty$-smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ that decays like $O(\|x\|^{-d})$ as $\|x\|\rightarrow \infty$, i.e., absolutely integrable along hyperplanes, but not necessarily absolutely integrable over all of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Here $\phi$ does not have to satisfy any of the moment conditions, even though the defining integrals are convergent since $\phi$ is Schwartz.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I realized this later.  However: the degree of the zero polynomial is $-\infty$, not 1.  In addition, if Pn is considered as a "spherical" homogeneous polynomial subject to trigonometric identity simplifications, how would you define its degree?

Comment: I don't think there is a uniquely defined degree in this case. But I don't think that matters in defining the moment conditions. Simply take $H_n$ to be the space of all functions realizable as a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$ evaluated on the sphere. Then the moment conditions say that $P_n$ must belong to $H_n$.

Comment: To be more clear, the proof of the moment conditions amounts to the identity:
$\int Rf(w,t) t^n dt = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x) \langle w,x\rangle^n dx$
for all $w = (w_1,...,w_n) \in \mathbb{S}^{d-1}$. The right-hand side may be formally expanded into a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$ in the variable $w$, and this is what is meant by a "degree n" spherical polynomial.

Comment: Then I think it would be less ambiguous to say that $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree <= n

Comment: That's not true, though. For example, $H_1$ as I've defined it does not contain constant functions, since there is no linear combination of $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ that gives a constant. Likewise,$H_2$ does not contain $\sin(\theta)$ or $\cos(\theta)$, since there is no linear combination of $\sin^2(\theta)$, $\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$, $\cos^2(\theta)$ to give you those functions, etc.

Comment: Ok I think your $H_n$ can probably be characterized as all homogeneous polynomials of degree $n-2k, k\in\{0, 1, \cdot, [n/2]$ where $[\cdot]$ denotes the floor function.  Or am I missing something else?

Comment: I think that's essentially correct. But, actually, there is a cleaner way to characterize the $H_n$ using spherical harmonics: $H_n$ is the space of harmonic polynomials up to degree $n$, where a harmonic polynomial is any polynomial whose Laplacian vanishes.  See Theorem 1.1.3. of Bai and Xu's "Approximation Theory
and Harmonic Analysis
on Spheres and Balls": https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-1-4614-6660-4.pdf